# error: call to a member function extension() on array

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

I am facing this error while storing images in s3 bucket here is my code check in this error In my local it is working but on Production showing this error

```
            $uploadedImages = [];

            $images = $request->file('subcatagories_template');

            foreach ($images as $key => $image) {
                // Generate a unique filename with the correct extension
                $filename = uniqid() . '.' . pathinfo($image->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            
                // Resize the image if needed (you can customize this part)
                $resizedImage = Image::make($image)->encode();
            
                // Store the image in S3/subcategoriesTemplate/{subcategory_id}
                $subcategory_id = $subcategory->id;
                $realPath = 'subcategoriesTemplate/' . $subcategory_id;
            
                // Check if the directory exists, if not, create it
                if (!Storage::disk('s3')->exists($realPath)) {
                    Storage::disk('s3')->makeDirectory($realPath);
                }
            
                // Upload the image to S3
                Storage::disk('s3')->put($realPath . '/' . $filename, $resizedImage->__toString(), 'public');
            
                // Get the URL path for the uploaded image
                $subcategory_templateUrl = Storage::disk('s3')->url($realPath . '/' . $filename);
            
                // Capture information about the uploaded image
                $uploadedImages[] = [
                    'path' => $subcategory_templateUrl,
                ];
            }
```

While I am passing key using [] array then I am getting error While not passing array I am not facing while but mutiple images is not storing I want to store mutilple images I am getting error in api

Comment: It would help to show where the error is happening, show the actual code at that line (including where you may be calling it if it's part of a library)

Comment: And check if you have the same version of the S3 library on your local machine and the production server.

Comment: Error is not there in code I think because I have tried to store mutiple images in local storage also it is working but there in prod it is not working showing same error while using array I didnt understand from where that error comes